# Hide UIPopoverController background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am loading a UIPopoverController that contains a UIImagePickerController, when the view loads it loads a seethrough view behind the popover, which if touched it dismisses the popover and the the cameraview inside it.

I would like to know if there is a way to remove this background view and control the dismiss myself with buttons.

My goal is to have some information to the left and the camera popover view to the right, but I cannot do this as some of the information is selectable i.e. textfields, and currently this background view is preventing selection of them.

This is my code for the popovercontroller and the UIImagePickerController.

```
- (void) cameraButtonSelected
{
    // set background
    UIView *cameraBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, screenHeight, screenWidth-64)];
    cameraBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cameraBG.alpha = 0.8;
    [self.view addSubview:cameraBG];

    // create picker
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        CGFloat scaleFactor=1.3f;
        picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -90 / 180.0), scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    }

    // create popover
    self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(500, 100, 0, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:NO];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(805, 650);
}
```

Comment: Note that documentation states that for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, the picker should be presented modally in full screen. I have experienced issues when presenting a camera picker in a popover. Thread lightly.

Comment: okay. thanks... wanted to avoid this but I think maybe i have to just display in full mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call, 
 `self.popOver.hidden = YES;` or `self.popOver.hidden = NO;`

If you want the pop0ver view to still be drawn but still hidden to the user, you can call `self.pop0ver.alpha = 0.0f;`

Comment: object 'popOver' is not kind of UIViewController. i.e it doesn't expose hidden or alpha properties. Please see interface declaration of UIPopoverController.